# WSO2 Siddhi standalone library - No extension exist for :timeBatch

Tags: wso2, osgi, siddhi

I´m trying to implement a wso2 siddhi library standalone solution into an osgi environment. Apart from using windows, it works so far. When I define a stream or a window for aggregations, I get the error message "No extension exist for :timeBatch". But timeBatch is shipped with Siddhi, so this message doesn't make sense. The libraries siddhi-core, siddhi-annotations, siddhi-query-api, siddhi-query-compiler are all required-plugins and queries without windows are built without problems.

Is there anything else I might have forgotten?

```
String espEventStream =
            "define Stream EspStream (temperature float, humidity float, brightness float); " +
                    "define window EspStreamWindow (temperature float, humidity float, brightness float) timeBatch(5sec); " +
                    " " +
                    "@info(name = 'query0') " +
                    "from EspStream " +
                    "insert into EspStreamWindow; "+
                    "@info(name = 'query1') " +
                    "from EspStreamWindow "+
                    "select avg(brightness) as avgBrightness, min(brightness) as minBrightness, max(brightness) as maxBrightness " +
                    "insert into EspStreamOut ;";
    SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();
    SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(espEventStream);
```

Edit: It works if I pack all dependencies into one single bundle and use this instead of using every dependency as a seperate bundle.

Comment: I just tried your code in a separate java project using SIddhi dependencies and it worked without an issue. I was testing on Siddhi version 4.2.17. What is your Siddhi dependency. Also make sure your dependencies are resolved within the environment

Comment: I´m using Siddhi 4.3.13. It seems so be working if I pack all dependencies into one single bundle instead of using a seperate bundle for every dependency. I just edited it in my question.

Comment: Did you check whether all bundles are active when using them as separate bundles. Within WSO2 Stream Processor product these dependencies are used as separate bundles and hence should work in your scenario as well

Comment: It works now with separate bundles as well. My mistake was making extra bundles out of these jars instead of using them as they are.